# dealing with HTML escaped content and writing it as HTML

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, escaping

I am porting a legacy project to django and have encountered a wierd database state, a filed content that has been HTML escaped:

```
&lt;p&gt;
    &lt;strong&gt;The &amp;lsquo;Unbundling&amp;rsquo; of Research is a secular, not cyclical, trend as it helps asset managers recognize and reward the value of research more independently&lt;/strong&gt;. &amp;nbsp;In 2002, then-New York Attorney General Eliot Spitzer accused major investment banks of promoting companies&amp;#39; shares in their
```

so that when I dump that out in djnago

```
<p>{{ object.field | safe }}</p>
```

the output is then escaped again:

```
&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;
```

truly frustrating.  I am new to djnago and I cannot I convert the escaped content to stream html out to get this format:

```
<p>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a [custom `unescape` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/):

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser    
from django import template   

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def unescape(value):
    return HTMLParser().unescape(value)
```

Here's the demo of what the logic inside does:

```
>>> from HTMLParser import HTMLParser 
>>> value = '&lt;p&gt;'
>>> HTMLParser().unescape(value)
u'<p>'
```

Here's how you can use it:

```
<p>{{ object.field | unescape | safe }}</p>
```

or, using [`filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#filter) template tag:

```
{% filter unescape|safe %}
    {{ value }}
{% endfilter %}
```

or, switching off autoescaping using [`autoescape`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape):

```
{% autoescape off %}
    {{ value | unescape }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: I am using the first format {{ object.field | unescape }} and I am getting the message filter undefined...  Any ideas?

Comment: @akaphenom have you put `{% load ... %}` to the top of your template?

Comment: Nope but I see it now on the djanogo custom template tags tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/  I should have ot soon

Comment: Also for those unaware place in a package ./templatetags/fileName.py  and import the fileName api with the tags in the template {% load fileName %}